# Как в данном примере используется интерфейс?

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Смотрю курс и не очень понимаю данное использование интерфейса.

Есть интерфейс, метод реализуется в классе FriendDataService:

```
public interface IFriendDataService
{
    IEnumerable<Friend> GetAll();
}
```

А вот в классе **MainViewModel** реализуется конструктор, в параметры которого передан объект интерфейса:

```
private IFriendDataService _friendDataService;

public MainViewModel(IFriendDataService friendDataService)
{
    Friends = new ObservableCollection<Friend>();
    _friendDataService = friendDataService;
}
```

Как и зачем мы создаем объект интерфейса, можно ли так делать?

Comment: `Как и зачем мы создаем объект интерфейса` объект интерфейса в приведенном вами коде нигде не создается

Comment: `можно ли так делать` - можно

Comment: Не только можно, но и нужно. Очень хорошая практика: этот приём используется для DI на конструкторе.

Comment: @AK рановато пока про DI заикаться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В конструктор передаётся экземпляр какого-то класса, который реализует интерфейс `IFriendDataService`.

"Объект интерфейса" - это нонсенс, т.к. нельзя создать экземпляр интерфейса, интерфейс можно только реализовать.

Т.е. там есть какой-то класс вроде:

```
public class MyFriendDataService : IFriendDataService {

    public IEnumerable<Friend> GetAll() {
        // тут что-то делает
    }
}
```

И, к примеру, создаётся экземпляр `MainViewModel` и туда передаётся экземпляр конкретного класса:

```
var model = new MainViewModel(new MyFriendDataService());
```

За счёт того, что в конструкторе параметр - это интерфейс `IFriendDataService`, можно не меняя логику при работе с `_friendDataService`подсунуть при создании `MainViewModel` какой-то другой класс, реализующий этот же интерфейс.

Comment: `private IFriendDataService _friendDataService;`
Вот это поле как можно обьяснить?

Comment: @ruffury это ссылка на объект, который прокинули в конструктор, который позже где-то будет использован. В чём, собственно, вопрос то? (: Думаю, в курсе это должно объясняться чуть дальше.

Comment: А, все, понял. Вот это прояснило ситуацию
"В конструктор передаётся экземпляр какого-то класса, который реализует интерфейс IFriendDataService. "

Comment: А если несколько классов реализуют этот интерфейс?

Comment: Все, туплю, можно не отвечать. Спасибо!

Comment: @ruffury я вместо резиновой уточки? (:

Comment: Скорее я ей являюсь